# Display a wait cursor while form is busy

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have an application that is doing some work that takes time and i wish to use the wait cursor but i cant find how.

```
Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor 'and some various me.Cursor / current.cursor 
CalulateBalance()
FTableAdapter.FillDateID(BudgetDataSet.FQuartaly)
FQuartalyDataGridView.Refresh()
MsgBox("Completed updating Balances", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
Cursor = Cursors.Default
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you are want to run your long processes on another thread you only have to stick in a `Application.DoEvents()` line after changing the cursor and before the long process.

```
Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor 'and some various me.Cursor / current.cursor 
Application.DoEvents()
CalulateBalance()
FTableAdapter.FillDateID(BudgetDataSet.FQuartaly)
FQuartalyDataGridView.Refresh()
MsgBox("Completed updating Balances", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
Cursor = Cursors.Default
```

Comment: Unfortunately i only get the wait cursor for 1/4 of a second?

Comment: What is `CalulateBalance()` doing exactly?

Comment: I have added the first two lines in the CalulateBalance() sub and it seem to work thanks.